# Problem with paragraph size

Tags: html, css

I've got problem with paragraph on my website: [naprawiamy.za.pl](http://naprawiamy.za.pl). As u can see there is a big white space in the text. What's that and how it got there? Could somebody tell me?

Comment: I can’t actually see the “big white space in the text”.

Comment: It's not obvious that there is a problem. Maybe use a screenshot to illustrate the problem, and show the code that is affected. Also, what browsers show this problem?

Comment: I'd assume this has something to do with your <div style = "story"> element.

Comment: No "big white space in the text" in IE6 or 7...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happen because the above `div` contains `img` that have `float:left`. So there is need to clear the float. Add `overflow:hidden` for the `div` with `img` tags and will fix the text below.

Comment: could you tell me more about this behaviour? What is clearing the float?

Comment: @oneat you can read the following article http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/

Answer (score 2):

Your code is written as:

```
<div id="main">
    <div>
       <img src="lol.png" id="logo" alt="logo serwisu">
       //more images
    </div>
   <div id="story" >
       Your Text
   </div>
</div>
```

Set the CSS Property

```
float:left
```

for

```
1. <div style="float:left">
2. <div id="story" style="float:left">
```